# Recursively Create ReadOnly Object in FlowJS

Tags: recursion, redux, flowtype

In redux, the state should be immutable. I would like Flow to prevent anyone from mutating that state. So, given an object of arbitrary depth:

```
type object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      d: string
    }
  },
  c: number
}
```

How can I create a new type that is recursively readonly, so that I **cannot** do:

```
let TestFunction = (param: $RecursiveReadOnly<object>) => {
  param.a.b.d = 'some string'
}
```

The builtin `$ReadOnly` utility of Flow will create a type like this, which **isn't** what is needed, because `b` & `d` are still writable:

```
{
  +a: {
    b: {
      d: string
    }
  },
  +c: number
}
```

I've been trying to use the `$Call` & `$ObjMap(i)`, but I can't figure out how to recursively travel an object in Flow. The objective is to have this:

```
{
  +a: {
    +b: {
      +d: string
    }
  },
  +c: number
}
```

Comment: I got it to work outside of the function, but not within. Maybe that will help: [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcJwIYBMB5AOwBsQAeQgLikICMArBYAPigF4oASPIsytwaMAsrjBUANFFCQA9gDMoAW1wBrHAhQZsrVgCgoRqPvwJSuZNAWJi8YOjnEV6zUjRYIVWgG8AvqwAFIQAlLRw7jqaBCTkVAZm8BZWUDZ2Dk4uGhHanhQAkrS4xCBB+WFQ+YbG+vBOqMBQACoQDQBitvaOzlzedEwsQWCWuMq0oeFaHth8sZSE7BzsPtXDyKMAdLgb9Bv4nFAA5KhyytANyOjEAOaH1cYPJkZWwCjOa6P6fvcmdcQNUCsMQEBxa7U6GWIgRWRlwvh+9Hhjyg+Foh2ArWAhyexm+Rm+fhCP30QP45C2Oz2B2Op3OwEuN0OQA)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5844

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [kalley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539605/kalley) for his solution. From what I understood, [kalley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539605/kalley) tried to make any object received by a function recursively read only. Since I really only needed known objects as parameters, this works perfectly:

```
// Type definition that works with arbitrary nested objects/arrays etc.
declare type RecursiveReadOnly<O: Object> = $ReadOnly<$ObjMap<O, typeof makeRecursive>>
declare type RecursiveReadOnlyArray<O: Object> = $ReadOnlyArray<$ReadOnly<$ObjMap<O, typeof makeRecursive>>>
type Recursive<O: Object> = $ObjMap<O, typeof makeRecursive>

declare function makeRecursive<F: Function>(F): F
declare function makeRecursive<A: Object[]>(A): $ReadOnlyArray<$ReadOnly<Recursive<$ElementType<A, number>>>>
declare function makeRecursive<O: Object>(O): RecursiveReadOnly<O>
declare function makeRecursive<I: string[] | boolean[] | number[]>(I): $ReadOnlyArray<$ElementType<I, number>>
declare function makeRecursive<I: string | boolean | number | void | null>(I): I

// Usage example.
type obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      d: string,
    }
  }
}


let TestFunction = (param: RecursiveReadOnly<obj>) => {
  param.a.b.d = 'some string' // Flow throws an error
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. It stopped working after Flow 0.88.0, but I managed to fix it with a small edit.

Change the first `makeRecursive` declaration to use `<I, O, F: I => O>(F): F` and it works again :)

I have a working Flow try but the URL is too long to post. Use this slug with bit.ly to see it, `3CJyoXr`